# Implementing Finite (Directed) Graphs In Idris

Tags: graph, dependent-type, idris

I'd like to implement finite, directed graphs in Idris.  Also I want to work with vertex maps `f : V -> X` from the vertex set to some other type / set.  Which would be the most natural approach here?

One option is to always chose `Fin n` for the vertex set.  This way, a graph can be straightforwardly implemented as its adjacency matrix, i.e. `Graph n = Vect n (Vect n Bool)`, and any vertex map as vector of type `Vect n a`.

On the other hand, I like the idea of defining `Graph a = SortedMap (a, a) Bool`.  This way, a few constructions seem more straightforward, e.g. the graph product of type `Graph a -> Graph b -> Graph (a, b)`.

But it is possible then to construct maleficent graph instances, where e.g. `(x, y)` is a key of `g` but `(y, x)` is not.  Also, if I want to write a function which takes a graph and a compatible vertex map, I don't know how to specify that the domains of both objects have to coincide.  Possibly `f : (g : Graph a) -> (m : SortedMap a b) -> {auto p : vertexList g = keys m} -> ...` where the functions `vertexList` and `keys` have to be written first?

A third definition would be `Graph a = (a, a) -> Bool` where `a` is supposed to be some finite type like `Fin n` or `(Fin m, Fin n)`.  Then vertex maps would simply be of type `a -> b`.

Comment: If you want to avoid constructing maleficent graphs read paper about algebraic constructions of graphs: https://github.com/snowleopard/alga-paper I find it really exciting. It's also written in Haskell so you shouldn't have problems with it. Maybe you can find some interesting ideas. It would be nice to see how dependent types can help with graphs.

Comment: Great stuff, hope to use this for my thesis (: